# Using Python/Pandas to transpose a dataframe with multiple column groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, transpose

I have tried a bunch of different ways to do this in Python, and I'm sure i'm missing something. My data is like this:

```
Date | Stock 1 | Stock 2 | Stock 3 
11-30-86    2.45    0.47021 1.45879  
12-31-86    -2.57   1.09626 -2.67784  
01-31-87    13.5    9.33911 11.14448  
02-28-87    3.99    4.63777 5.96181
```

What I'd like to do is transpose the data BY stock name (column name) and have it rendered like this:

```
Stock Name | Date | Return
Stock 1 11-30-86    2.45  
Stock 2 11-30-86    0.47021  
Stock 3 11-30-86    1.45879  
Stock 1 12-31-86    -2.57  
Stock 2 12-31-86    1.09626  
Stock 3 12-31-86    -2.67784  
Stock 1 01-31-87    13.5  
Stock 2 01-31-87    9.33911  
Stock 3 01-31-87    11.14448  
Stock 1 02-28-87    3.99  
Stock 2 02-28-87    4.63777  
Stock 3 02-28-87    5.96181
```

I've trying different permutations of Pandas pivot/unpivot and transpose but I can't seem to get this working - I only ever get the entire table pivoted, where I want to use the different column names are BY groups and get the resulting single column.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please include the relevant code and examples of how it is failing within your question. You have described the problem well, but we're looking for code on Stack Overflow. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry @StefanCrain - my bad here, I will do better in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using melt:

```
df.melt(id_vars='Date', var_name='Stock Name', value_name='Return')
```

Output:

```
        Date Stock Name    Return
0   11-30-86    Stock 1   2.45000
1   12-31-86    Stock 1  -2.57000
2   01-31-87    Stock 1  13.50000
3   02-28-87    Stock 1   3.99000
4   11-30-86    Stock 2   0.47021
5   12-31-86    Stock 2   1.09626
6   01-31-87    Stock 2   9.33911
7   02-28-87    Stock 2   4.63777
8   11-30-86    Stock 3   1.45879
9   12-31-86    Stock 3  -2.67784
10  01-31-87    Stock 3  11.14448
11  02-28-87    Stock 3   5.96181
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Scott_Boston. This is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways `melt` and `stack`

```
df.melt('Date')
Out[1303]: 
        Date variable     value
0   11-30-86   Stock1   2.45000
1   12-31-86   Stock1  -2.57000
2   01-31-87   Stock1  13.50000
3   02-28-87   Stock1   3.99000
4   11-30-86   Stock2   0.47021
5   12-31-86   Stock2   1.09626
6   01-31-87   Stock2   9.33911
7   02-28-87   Stock2   4.63777
8   11-30-86   Stock3   1.45879
9   12-31-86   Stock3  -2.67784
10  01-31-87   Stock3  11.14448
11  02-28-87   Stock3   5.96181
df.set_index('Date').stack().reset_index()
Out[1304]: 
        Date level_1         0
0   11-30-86  Stock1   2.45000
1   11-30-86  Stock2   0.47021
2   11-30-86  Stock3   1.45879
3   12-31-86  Stock1  -2.57000
4   12-31-86  Stock2   1.09626
5   12-31-86  Stock3  -2.67784
6   01-31-87  Stock1  13.50000
7   01-31-87  Stock2   9.33911
8   01-31-87  Stock3  11.14448
9   02-28-87  Stock1   3.99000
10  02-28-87  Stock2   4.63777
11  02-28-87  Stock3   5.96181
```

Comment: BOOM! That's the ticket! Nice and elegant - thank you @Wen! I am used to lingo from working with SAS, so I was stuck googling/searching for transpose and somehow didn't find df.melt